# Cant do anything after ftp transfer

Tags: bash, ftp, download, unzip

I wrote script for downloading zip files from ftp, and than unziping each different extension to own folder.
**download.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -in sitehere.com << EOF
user username pass
binary
hash
lcd ./temp
mget *.zip
bye
unzip -n './temp/*.zip' -d ../../base/images/ *.TIF
unzip -n './temp/*.zip' -d ../../base/dbfs/ *.dbf
```

But after downloading i have in terminal i have 2 errors "Unknown format".
Tell me please what I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `EOF` at the end of the FTP command list. Without it the two `unzip` commands are sent to the FTP server.

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -in sitehere.com << EOF
user username pass
binary
hash
lcd ./temp
mget *.zip
bye
EOF

unzip -n './temp/*.zip' -d ../../base/images/ *.TIF
unzip -n './temp/*.zip' -d ../../base/dbfs/ *.dbf
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to close your [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) ? i.e. Put `EOF` on a separate line when you want to disconnect from ftp.

Answer (score 0):

```
ftp -n 192.168.1.111<<EOF
user USERNAME
pass PASSWORD 
prompt off
mput file1.txt
bye
EOF

ftp -n 192.168.9.122<<EOF
user USERNAME
pass PASSWORD 
prompt off
mput file2.txt
bye

 Second file i.e. file2 is not getting uploaded
```